# How to make sure the UIView -drawRect: is drawing with contentScaleFactor of 1.0f?

Tags: iphone, retina-display

I've implemented -drawRect: to draw something, and I don't want that this drawing happens on a larger bitmap on the retina display. How can I make sure that this bitmap is always exactly the same across all devices?

I tried to set `self.contentScaleFactor = 1.0f;` in the initialzier but that didn't help. The system seems to change this back to 2.0f automatically... In my NSLog I keep getting

> contentScaleFactor = 2.0f

How to make sure it's 1.0f?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a bit late, but if anyone needed...

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.contentScaleFactor = 1
}
```